# How does one run QML tests on a Ubuntu Touch Phone?

Tags: application-development, qml, testing

My application has QML tests using QtTests that I run locally on the desktop via **qmltestrunner**. I am interested in running these tests on the device to simulate real conditions like the on-screen keyboard being visible and so on. How do I run it on the device?

As an example take the [Ubuntu Clock App](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-clock-app) whose source code you can get by,

```
bzr branch lp:ubuntu-clock-app
```

On the desktop I run the tests by by,

```
cd ubuntu-clock-app/tests/unit
qmltestrunner -input tst_alarmLabel.qml (inside tests/unit folder)
```

I pushed the source code to the (phone, x86 Emulator) and tried running it by,

```
adb push ubuntu-clock-app /tmp
phablet-shell
cd /tmp/ubuntu-clock-app/tests/unit
qmltestrunner -input tst_alarmLabel.qml
```

However I got the following crash,

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qmltestrunner: invalid option -- 'i'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qmltestrunner: invalid option -- 'n'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qmltestrunner: invalid option -- 'p'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qmltestrunner: invalid option -- 'u'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qmltestrunner: invalid option -- 't'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When trying to run without the -input parameter since it is not recognised, I got,

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:/tmp/tests/unit$ qmltestrunner tst_alarmLabel.qml 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Note: I had to install **qtdeclarative5-dev-tools** and **qtdeclarative5-test-plugin** on the phone to get qmltestrunner and QTest 1.0.

Comment: Just a note, qmltestrunner is not the same on the device (aka, compiled for arm) as it is on the desktop. It does not have the same options / support, which is why you are seeing the invalid option.

Comment: I would also be curious if the x86 emulator gives you better results. The binary should be the same, as well as you would be running under X and not under MIR, which might be the source of your segfaults on the device.

Comment: @balloons I tried this morning on the x86 emulator. First it still didnt recognize the argument -input and produced the same error as posted in the question. 

So I tried "qmltestrunner tst_alarmLabel.qml" which straight produced a segmentation fault (core dumped) crash.